# When migrate a question to Mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, mathoverflow

I have some questions that received some upvote but no answer in many months.  For someone of these I've started a bounty, but without success (one example was: [Multitangent to a polynomial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076688/multitangent-to-a-polynomial-function), and now I've one active bounty at:[Nested solutions of a quadratic equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454204/nested-solutions-of-a-quadratic-equation)  and I hope that some answer comes).

I'm thinking to post the same questions to Mathoverflow, but I see that this site is for professionals, and maybe that my questions are not so interesting for professional mathematicians, so I don't know if this is a good idea.  There is some ''rule of good manners'' or ''best practice'' that I must  know?

Comment: You are basically asking what questions are suitable on mathoverflow. So this is off topic here, I think you can ask (or find answers) in mathoverflow meta.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17161/didnt-get-an-answer-on-math-se-how-to-ask-at-mathoverflow-ii, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration and probably some other posts tagged ([meta-tag:mathoverflow]).

Comment: There is a [thread to draw attention to questions on math.se on meta.MO](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se) It is an intermediate option.